# Application Id and reading/writing files

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing and reading files from my iOS application:

```
func saveChecklistItems() {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
    archiver.encode(items, forKey: "ChecklistItems")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    print("save \(dataFileDir())")
    data.write(toFile: dataFileDir(), atomically: true)
}

func loadChecklistItems() {

    print("load \(dataFileDir())")
    let path = dataFileDir()
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        if let data = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: path) {
            do {
                let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data as Data)
                items = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "ChecklistItems") as! [CheckListItem]
                unarchiver.finishDecoding()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }                
        }
    }
}

func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
    return paths[0]
}

func dataFileDir() -> String {
    return documentsDirectory().appending("Checklists.plist")
}
```

But every time I press Run in Xcode application is deployed on my iPhone with new ID:

> save
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4684F231-7A41-461C-AD5C-FB0F66A9DA31/DocumentsChecklists.plist
>
> load
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CFE42D59-6F3F-4D47-96B5-4F81C640127A/DocumentsChecklists.plist

It is my first steps in iOS development and I am wondering what do I need to do in this case ? Set application id as static ? Or something else ?

Comment: Are you deleting the app between runs?

Comment: No, I don't delete it. But I run it from my MacBook in debugger, so it is looks like the Xcode build and redeploy it every time I have pressed Run.

Comment: You are missing a `/` between the directory name and file name. Fix that and your app will be able to find a previously saved file. Consider using `URL` instead then you can call `appendPathComponent(_:)` without having to worry about any `/`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, Thank you

Comment: This is expected behaviour. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)` will always return the correct path to you, so use that to resolve the file in-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use URL instead of strings when working with folders and files

```
func documentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

func dataFileDir() -> URL {
    return documentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Checklists.plist")
}
```

and change your write to

```
try data.write(to: dataFileDir(),  options: .atomic)
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me.